# Magento 1.9 - Adding a custom link to a menu item

Tags: html, redirect, url-rewriting, magento-1.9, categories

I'm on magento 1.9 and one problem I've never been able to figure out is how to get a top menu item to redirect to an alternate category page as magento keeps try to revert to its default

I've tried to do it in 'URL rewrite management' but it does'nt allow it or just bypasses the setting to go to default

Here is the behavior below

https://www.useloom.com/share/a13b2814c916425fbdaf125591593549

The only workable solution I have found is to add this to the 'customer layout update' for every item i wish to redirect, however, as you can see on the video, there is a delay in the redirect and it takes the visitor to a page without products :( for obvious reasons this aint ideal

Thanks in advance

```html
<reference name="head">
    <block type="core/text" name="SOME.BLOCK.NAME.HERE">
        <action method="setText">
            <text><![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript">location.replace("https://poshh.co.uk/bathroom/toilets.html");</script>]]></text>
        </action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

this lies in the nature of how your top menu is implemented. The most flexible way is to use a static cms block as navigation and category link widgets for each item to keep up with url rewrites.